# ZFS Drive both in pool and hot spare?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, zfs

I'm running a RAIDZ2 setup on my server. This is mounted as /NAS, and not involved in the boot process. Running Ubuntu Server 18.10. I had two drives go out on me at the same time. I have already replaced and resilvered one of the drives, but when I detached the faulted drive, it did not remove the spare from my "spares" for the pool. When I did the same procedure to remove the other faulted drive, it removed the spare and added it to the pool, which is what I intended to happen.

Is this a different replacement function or a bug? I could not find any instances online where someone had a spare active in the pool still showing in spares as IN USE with the faulted drive it replaced removed. It doesn't seem to be causing any issues, I just think it might be a bug? If no one can help me determine this is an intended function that I accidentally implemented, I will submit a bug report.

```
me@myserver:~$ sudo zpool status NAS
  pool: NAS
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Sun Sep  1 05:28:25 2019
        59.3G scanned out of 2.42T at 46.8M/s, 14h42m to go
        9.88G resilvered, 2.39% done
config:

        NAME                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        NAS                               ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                        ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B9JGR5TF  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B9JA0NHF  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B8J92GBZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2bb3b8bb0        ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_YAHWBY3T  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee265d7405a        ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          wwn-0x50014ee265d7405a          INUSE     currently in use

errors: No known data errors
```

This is the guide I followed for replacement. Each of these replacements were spares which reside in their own sata slot. No physical replacement has taken place. These were in the chassis for this purpose, because this is an off-site machine.

Steps taken:

```
zpool replace NAS <bad_drive> <spare_drive>
(New drive is resilvering)
zpool offline NAS <bad_drive>
zpool detach NAS <bad_drive>
```

I am unsure whether this is a bug, but I was able to remove this drive from the spare list and active pool. To do this:

```
zpool add NAS spare <additional_drive>
zpool replace NAS <spare_drive> <additional_drive>
zpool detach NAS <spare_drive>
zpool remove NAS <spare_drive>
```

Now I can add "spare_drive" back into the pool, but for sake of example here, I will leave that step out.

```
me@myserver:/$ sudo zpool status NAS
  pool: NAS
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Mon Sep  2 02:50:45 2019
        204G scanned out of 2.42T at 39.1M/s, 16h34m to go
        33.9G resilvered, 8.22% done
config:

        NAME                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        NAS                               ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                        ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B9JGR5TF  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B9JA0NHF  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_B8J92GBZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee2bb3b8bb0        ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-HUA722020ALA330_YAHWBY3T  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdh                           ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)

errors: No known data errors
```

You will notice, however, that I have the replacement drive identified in the pool as sdh. Before I reboot the machine, I plan to change this to /dev/disk/by-id. This is important because sd(x) is determined by boot order, and these will change when disks are added, removed, or fail between reboots. To rectify this, I will use:

```
sudo zpool export [pool name]
sudo zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id [pool name]
```

See this link for more details on that subject in particular:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/967091/zpool-degrades-when-plugging-in-a-drive

Thanks,
rsturtle

Comment: Could you elaborate on the exact steps taken?  You removed one of the bad drives, then reinserted a new one and resilvered and then resilvered the second faulty one?  Correct?  Please [edit] your question to provide the HW manipulations and commands you executed in a chronological order to be 100% sure as I think I can guess what happened, but don't want to answer until you confirmed.

Comment: I have elaborated on the steps I took to produce this. I did not physically replace any drives. These were powered on hot-spares with their own sata port assignments. I simply tried to replace the non-working disks with spares which were waiting to be powered on to take replacement.

Comment: I would file a bug and answer your own question  when you get feed-back...  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**